# How to turn all columns into just name and value SQL (like pd.unstack(level=-1) in Python)

Tags: sql, unpivot

Suppose we have a table like:

```
date   element1    element2   element3....

date1    42          30           63
date2    32          23           2 
date3    23          3            15
```

How to turn this table into something like

```
date   elements   value

date1  element1    42
date2  element1    32
date3  element1    23
date1  element2    30
date1  element3 ...
```

It's like a kind of pivot but I don't get it. If someone knows a shortcut for this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You want in `SQL` or `Python` ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unpivot` with SQL server and Oracle.

```
select date, 
    elements,
    value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for elements in (element1, element2, element3)
) unpiv
```

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL` you can use `union all`  :

```
select t.*
from ( (select date, 'element1' as elements, element1 from table t) union all 
       (select date, 'element2' as elements, element2 from table t) union all
       (select date, 'element3' as elements, element3 from table t) union all
        . . . 
     ) t
order by date, elements;
```

Note : Different databases have a own flavor to run this in different way.